# Embed Youtube Video Warnings

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, youtube, warnings

So in my app, I embed a Youtube video using the following code:

```
- (void)embedYouTube:(NSString*)url frame:(CGRect)frame {  
    NSString* embedHTML = @"\ 
    <html><head>\ 
    <style type=\"text/css\">\ 
    body {\ 
        background-color: transparent;\ 
    color: white;\ 
    }\ 
    </style>\ 
    </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\ 
    <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \ 
    width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\ 
    </body></html>";  

    NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, url, frame.size.width, fra    me.size.height];  
    if(videoView == nil) {  
        videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        videoView.delegate = self;
        [self.view addSubview:videoView];  
    }  
    [videoView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];  
}
```

Formatted exactly as shown above.  But, I get 11 warnings, all saying:

> Backslash and Newline separated by space

So my question is, how can I fix that?  I'm not really familiar with HTML so I don't really know what I can and can't do with that.  Thanks in advance

**Edit:**
I brought all the HTML onto one line, and it reduced my warnings from 11 to 1, which says

> Unknown escape sequence '/x20'

and here is what the code looks like with that error:

```
    NSString* embedHTML = @"\ <html><head>\ <style type=\"text/css\">\ body {\ background-color: transparent;\ color: white;\ }\ </style>\ </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\ <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \ width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\ </body></html>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although human friendly reading, by actually putting line breaks in there this is essentially breaking your NSString, also make sure you don't escape new lines, won't work, try out the following:

```
NSString* embedHTML = @"<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">body { background-color: transparent; color: white;}</style></head><body style=\"margin:0\"><embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed></body></html>";  

NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, url, frame.size.width, fra    me.size.height];  
if(videoView == nil) {  
    videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    videoView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:videoView];  
}  
[videoView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: You have some backslashes followed by a space left in there.

Answer (score 1):

> Backslash and Newline separated by space

That's saying all you need to know - you have a space somewhere after a backslash. This doesn't have to do with HTML, but rather the preprocessor - the newline has to be immediately after the backslash for it to be escaped.

To avoid stumbling over this issue, you can use a multiline string:

```
NSString* embedHTML =  
    @"<html><head>"
     "<style type=\"text/css\">"
     // ... etc.
     "</body></html>";
```

... or just load the HTML from the resources instead of hard-coding it.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the formatting. Put all the html on one line.

Comment: Can I do that - is that allowed?

Comment: can you edit in what your new code looks like? I might be able to get a better idea of the error from that.

Comment: I dont have the right environment set up here, but in the original code, shouldn't `(NSString*)url frame` be `(NSString *)urlString frame` ?

Comment: Try this instead  `NSString* embedHTML = @"<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">body {background-color: transparent;color: white;}</style></head><body style=\"margin:0\"><embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed></body></html>";`